# Correct way to set up an addressBook instance variable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

Maybe someone can answer this one easily. I working on an iphone app where to get info for each row in cellForRowAtIndexPath I was creating a new address book each time calling:

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

This works fine other than it's slow and does not feel right to be creating a new ab for each row. So I created an addressBook instance variable but can't seem to use it without crashing. 
(Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.)
I imagine that I'm not setting it up right, but have have had no luck finding anything specifically about this in the documentation.

Thanks a million in advance to anyone who can help.

In my .h file I did this:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook;


@property(nonatomic, readwrite) ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
```

Then in my .m file:

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {

        addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating an `ABAddressBookRef` for each row?  They all point to the same shared system address book.  It might make more sense to just hove one that is used by all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When do you release the addressBook by CFRelease(addressBook) ? If the memory is not enough, the ABAddressBookCreate() will return a nil object. The C-based addressBook.framework API cannot work with nil object, and it will crash with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Im releasing it in the dealloc method like this:  - (void)dealloc {
 CFRelease(addressBook);}  Note: it crashed even when the address book only contains 2 or 3 records.

Comment: I think there are logical errors in another places. The information is too less to identify why you crash.

Comment: Yes thanks. It must be a secondary cause, but what I really wanted to know is whether the above code is the correct way to set up an addressBook ivar? Because when I create the AB directly in cellForRowAtIndexPath and change nothing else it works. The idea was to test performance both ways, but...

Comment: Generally, I will cast ABAddressBookRef to (NSObject *) for property of controller. And when I need it, I will cast back to original ABAddressBookRef.

Comment: The most objects inside addressbook.framework need to check whether it is NULL or not. Those API cannot accept NULL object for parameter.

Comment: Yes NULL was the problem. Thanks for your help.